# How to configure aws-sdk with amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I built a react native app with amplify. Now I would like the app to poll an sqs queue. To do this, I need to use the aws-sdk.

Can I configure aws-sdk to use the same credentials as amplify? If so, how?

Thanks!